# how to hide carbon menu in wso2

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have deployed wso2am4.0.0 on my vm. I am going to hide some menus in `https://localhost:9443/carbon` but don't know how to achive that.
I want to hide menus like below:
[image]

Comment: One option is to create a separate role and assign required permissions only. Then you can apply that role to a user. When that user logs in, it will only show available options.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience these menu's can't be hidden unless you decide to change the UI design yourself. Users who log in will only be shown submenus inside these menus when they have the correct role for them. So for example a user would not see the "Datasources", "Message tracing" and "Server roles" listed there if they don't have the roles to support that.